# Queued Poission processes

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, poisson-process

Imagine a large factory with a few stations, where each item the factory produces must go through all stations in order. Each station processes items at a fixed rate, say $\lambda_i$, and there's some delay involved in moving each items between stations, say $\Delta t_i$.

I'm wondering how I can calculate:

1. The expected "dead time" - The time each station is waiting for new items to come in.
2. The total rate for processing items in the factory.

Clearly, we must have that $\lambda_{i+1}\ge\lambda_i$, otherwise we run into the "*I Love Lucy*" [infamous chocolate scene](https://youtu.be/8NPzLBSBzPI?t=33). But assuming that's the case, how do I go about calculating this? I've been reading up about continuous time Markov chains which seem to be related, where for this problem the transition matrix would only have a non-zero super-diagonal, but I'm not quite sure how to adapt them to this problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean?  It sounds like there is a source that produces a periodic arrival process of rate $\lambda$ (so it generates 1 arrival every $1/\lambda$ seconds), and these go through a tandem of deterministic-service time queues?  Is that correct?  In that case, if $T_i$ is the fixed service time of queue $i$, then you just need $\lambda \leq 1/T_i$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., k\}$.  There is no need to have $1/T_{i+1} \geq 1/T_i$.

Comment: Also, the title says "Poisson" but I do not see "Poisson" anywhere in the problem formulation. With these deterministic arrivals, service times, and propagation delays, the output process at each station is just a delayed version of its input. There is never any real queueing and each station has at most one item at any given time.  Little's theorem ensures the long term fraction of time that station $i$ is busy is equal to $\lambda T_i$, which is also the case with any stochastic source arrival process of rate $\lambda$ arrivals/sec (as long as $\lambda \leq 1/T_i$ for all $i$).

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a tandem of $k$ deterministic service time queues with service times $T_i$ seconds, for $i \in \{1, \ldots, k\}$.  For each $i \in \{1, ..., k-1\}$, the departures of queue $i$ go to the input of queue $i+1$. Let $P_i$ be the fixed propagation delay experienced after service at queue $i$. Let $N(t)$ be the stochastic arrival process to queue 1, where (for $t \geq 0$) $N(t)$ represents the total number of arrivals during the interval $[0,t]$. Assume $N(t)$ has *rate $\lambda$ arrivals/sec*, in the sense that: 
$$ \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \frac{N(t)}{t} = \lambda \quad \mbox{ with prob 1} $$
An example arrival process $N(t)$ is a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$. Assume that $\lambda < 1/T_i$ for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, k\}$.

Since the departures of queue $i$ are spaced at least $T_i$ seconds apart, and the propagation delay $P_i$ does not disturb the relative spacing between jobs, if $T_{i+1}\leq T_i$ then queue $i+1$ just acts as a pure delay line with delay $D_{i+1}=T_{i+1}$.  You can replace all such queues with pure delay lines with delay equal to their service time, and the only remaining queues form a tandem with non-decreasing service times.

This is a special case of a problem I looked at a few years ago in:  "Equivalent Models for Queueing Analysis of Deterministic Service Time Tree Networks" (Trans Information Theory 2005):

http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~mjneely/pdf_papers/equiv_revise_it.pdf

As in that paper, the output process of the system is equivalent to a system where the first "bottleneck queue" $b$ (the one with the largest service time $T_b=T_{max}$) is isolated and all other queues $i \neq b$ are replaced by pure delay lines of duration $D_i=T_i$.  In particular, the average delay in the total system is equal to: 
$$ \mbox{Total avg delay} = \sum_{i=1}^k P_i + \sum_{i \in \{1, ..., k\}, i \neq b} T_i + \overline{W} $$
where $\overline{W}$ is the average delay in a single queue with deterministic service time $T_{max}$ and with input process $N(t)$.  In particular, if $N(t)$ is Poisson of rate $\lambda$ and $\lambda T_{max} < 1$ then: 
$$ \mbox{Total avg delay} = \sum_{i=1}^k P_i + \sum_{i=1}^k T_i + \frac{\lambda T_{max}^2}{2(1-\lambda T_{max})}$$
where the above uses the standard M/D/1 queue formula $\overline{W} = T_{max} + \frac{\lambda T_{max}^2}{2(1-\lambda T_{max})}$. 
Of course, Little's theorem also ensures that $\rho_i = \lambda T_i$, where $\rho_i$ is the fraction of time that queue $i$ is nonempty.

The above paper also gives average queue sizes at each queue in a bit more general situation of a tree network with multiple source processes.